# Use jasmine-node to test meteor application with auto-test

Tags: node.js, meteor, jasmine, jasmine-node

I'm using jasmine-node to test my Meteor application and I want to use the auto-test feature so I don't have to rerun the tests all the time by myself.

My meteor application folder structure is like this:

```
server
    foo.coffee
tests
    foo.spec.coffee
```

And with the spec file I want to test code which is located in foo.coffee. I start jasmine-node with this args:

```
jasmine-node ./ --autotest --coffee --test-dir tests
```

And now I would *assume* that the autotest feature will react on all changes in the root folder but it just reacts on changes in the test folder. And I can't start it in the root folder because I get an error in the .meteor files (and I don't want to have jasmine testing/including the meteor code anyway).

So I want to have jasmine rerun the tests even if I change code in the server folder. How can I achieve that?

Comment: I can't find anything in the docs on ignoring directories, maybe you could make a directories with symlinks to tests & server and autotest that directories?

Comment: Anyone has a better solution for this???

Answer (score 2):

Use the --watch parameter along with --autotest and specify the directories that contain whatever files you want to have watched.

Comment: Note: jasmine-node 2.0.0 is now use --autoTest --watchFolders <yourfolderToWatch> .